# Activator.CreateInstance with an Interface parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, abstract-class

I have a Reflection method, which I load an Instance of an class with a specific name. I have an abstract class which define my classes. Now I also have an interface in the constructor of this abstract class. It's a bit hard to explain and I'm not sure if it's a correct way to implement my problem. But here is my source code, which should explain the most:

Program:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int result;

        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            string jobName = args[0];

            Type[] types = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Task)).GetTypes();
            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                if (type.Name == jobName)
                {
                    //Here is my problem. I need my Interface instead of null
                    _job = (Task)Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);
                }
            }

            if (_job != null)
            {
                result = _job.Run(args);
            }
        }

        //Dispose the Job
        _job = null;
    }
```

Task:

```
public abstract class Task
{
    public IArgument Argument;

    protected Task(IArgument argument)
    {
        Argument = argument;
    }

    public int Run(string[] args)
    {
        int result;

        if (SetArguments(args))
        {
            result = Work();
        }          
        return result;
    }

    protected abstract int Work();
```

Interface:

```
public interface IArgument
{
    bool SetArguments(string[] args);
}
```

Now I can create an "Task" class and an "Argument" class:

```
public class ImportArgument : IArgument
{
    public bool SetArguments(string[] args)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class ImportTask : Task
{
    protected override int Work()
    {            
        return 1;
    }

    public ImportTask(IArgument argument) : base(argument)
    {
        Argument = new ArticleImportArgument();
    }
}
```

What do you guys think. Is there a way where I can create an Instance of the task class with an Interface in the constructor? Is there another way to solve this problem? I could also create an abstract method in my Task class where I have to implement my Interface, but I think the constructor would be a better way.

Comment: So what is the actual problem? Doesn't your code work if you provide a value instead of null?

Comment: What kind of value. At this point I don't know what kind of "Argument" I will pass. Every implementation of Task could have it's own implementation of IArgument. But I can't pass IArgument as a parameter, it's an interface. I also tried it with an abstract IArgument implementation, but then I have the same problem. I also tried it with an "object".

Comment: The snippet leaves little to the imagination, you'll have to create an instance of ImportArgument and pass it to the constructor.  Any class that implements IArgument will do but you only showed us one.